# Como extrair dados de uma QuerySet do Django

Tags: postgresql, django, csv, importação

Tenho uma tabela com algumas informações, o nome do funcionário, pis, data e hora, o campo hora registra o horário do registro no relógio de ponto, estes registros estão todos na mesma coluna, por exemplo: Funcionário 1, tem quatro registros, entrada manhã, saída manhã, entrada tarde e saída tarde, mas todos esses horários estão na mesma coluna, o que eu preciso é separar isso e levar o nome e os horários dele para uma nova tabela, mas cada horário, em seu respectivo campo.

Se alguém puder ajudar com lógica dessa implementação, fico grato. Pode até ser também antes da importação do arquivo CSV, porque estes dados são importados a a partir de um CSV mas do jeito que estão. Se eu puder fazer isso antes mesmo da importação, resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Na importação do arquivo você poderia fazer algo assim:

Supondo que seu model tem todos os campos citado acima e o arquivo tivesse no seguinte formato: nome,pis,horario1,horario2,horario3,horario4.

```
for line in file.readlines():
    data = line.split(',')
    funcionario = Funcionario(nome=data[0], pis=data[1], horario1=data[3] ...)
    funcionario.save()
```